# FabricJS canvas cant select any objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I'm stuck on a canvas problem after loading a valid JSON object into a canvas via 'loadFromJSON'. The canvas renders a valid canvas with objects and even the right background image. For some reason, I cant select anything. Not even the blue selection box is showing if I try to click and select a couple of objects. I'm sure the object is valid, because I've pasted a valid tutorial object into the loadFromJSON and my JSON object into the jsfiddle tutorial.

If I click on the right mouse button... I get a save-image option, which looks a bit strange if you ask me.

This is my code:

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(data, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(object, o) {
    o = $.fn.mapCanvasFieldset(object); // custom function
});

canvas.renderAll();
```

JSON object (data var):

```
{
   "objects":[
      {
         "type":"image",
         "originX":"left",
         "originY":"top",
         "left":133,
         "top":108,
         "width":267,
         "height":80,
         "fill":"rgb(0,0,0)",
         "stroke":null,
         "strokeWidth":0,
         "strokeDashArray":null,
         "strokeLineCap":"butt",
         "strokeLineJoin":"miter",
         "strokeMiterLimit":10,
         "scaleX":0.33,
         "scaleY":0.33,
         "angle":0,
         "flipX":false,
         "flipY":false,
         "opacity":1,
         "shadow":null,
         "visible":true,
         "clipTo":null,
         "backgroundColor":"",
         "fillRule":"nonzero",
         "globalCompositeOperation":"source-over",
         "transformMatrix":null,
         "skewX":0,
         "skewY":0,
         "src":"",
         "filters":[],
         "resizeFilters":[],
         "crossOrigin":"",
         "alignX":"none",
         "alignY":"none",
         "meetOrSlice":"meet"
      }
   ],
   "background":"",
   "backgroundImage":{
      "type":"image",
      "originX":"left",
      "originY":"top",
      "left":0,
      "top":0,
      "width":350,
      "height":350,
      "fill":"rgb(0,0,0)",
      "stroke":null,
      "strokeWidth":0,
      "strokeDashArray":null,
      "strokeLineCap":"butt",
      "strokeLineJoin":"miter",
      "strokeMiterLimit":10,
      "scaleX":1,
      "scaleY":1,
      "angle":0,
      "flipX":false,
      "flipY":false,
      "opacity":1,
      "shadow":null,
      "visible":true,
      "clipTo":null,
      "backgroundColor":"",
      "fillRule":"nonzero",
      "globalCompositeOperation":"source-over",
      "transformMatrix":null,
      "skewX":0,
      "skewY":0,
      "src":"",
      "filters":[],
      "resizeFilters":[],
      "crossOrigin":"",
      "alignX":"none",
      "alignY":"none",
      "meetOrSlice":"meet"
   }
}
```

**Edit:**
Maybe crucial information; I'm loading my canvas inside a Fancybox

Comment: The `src` attribute for both your image object and the background image is empty.  That might be part of your problem.

Comment: I've emptied it myself because of a local address. In the real object, its filled with a valid src url.

Comment: Allright, so I debugged a bit more which made me discover that a Fabric JS canvas inside a Fancybox is causing this problem. I can select all object if I put the same object outside of the Fancybox... the content inside the box is loaded by Ajax, so maybe the canvas cant register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, after a ton of debugging I finally solved this issue. For some reason, all canvasses were put to display: none. This is why the newly DOM generated  didnt show-up so it could be clicked.